# Change level of python fileConfig logger

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger configured from a file and would like to change the level of my logging without having to change the .conf file, but instead using inline code;

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('..\\LoggingConfig\\loggingfile.conf')

logging.StreamHandler.setLevel(logging.info)

logging.debug("Debug")
logging.info("Info")
```

This should only print the "Info" log line to the screen. I don't know on which object to call the setLevel()! logging.StreamHandler.setLevel(logging.info) is just a stab in the dark after 30 mins searching...

The loggingfile.conf file;

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
handlers=screen
level=NOTSET

[formatter_modfunc]
format=%(module)-20s  %(funcName)-25s %(levelno)-3s: %(message)s

[handlers]
keys=screen

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=modfunc
level=DEBUG
args=(sys.stdout,)
qualname=screen
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `setLevel` on your `Logger` instance.

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('your.module.file.name')
LOGGER.setLevel(_level)
LOGGER.info('foo')
```

If you are only using the basic logger, you can do it like this

```
logging.basicConfig(level=_level)
logging.info('foo')
```

See http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html

Comment: Great that did it, I needed to know how to get the instance, used `loggerInstance = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 6):

When using logging.config.fileConfig and you want to dynamically change level for all child loggers at once, you can...

a) [set level](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) for [root logger](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger):

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

b) [disable](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.disable) other levels

```
logging.disable(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Everything else I've tried failed. Only this answer (which is unfortunately not marked as the correct one) actually does it for me. For some reason if you do a basicConfig, then later do another basicConfig, the latter doesn't change the logging level. Only this method does the subsequent change. Wish I understood why.

Comment: [The call to basicConfig() should come before any calls to debug(), info() etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration facility, only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent calls are effectively no-ops.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)